# ORCID and its QR-code on business card back cover as a researcher?

Tags: digital-researcher-id

I am thinking to include my ORCID on my business card back cover as a researcher.

I wanna know if this is necessary or too much.

Comment: Between necessary and too much there is unnecessary. You can answer for yourself if you are someone who likes to have a gadget on their business card.

Comment: @henning What do you think about QR code of vCard?

Comment: I personally like the idea but never thought of it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary.

It is not too much.

Note that the back of your business card might be occupied, though:

- Multilingual business cards sometimes feature another language on either side. (Although this approach is obviously limited as soon as you want to include more than two languages.)
- Business cards sometimes feature a QR code with all the business card information in [vCard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) on their back side. (IMHO, all business cards should have this. There is no real excuse not to.) If that is the case, it depends on your stylistic preferences whether or not to add one or more smaller QR codes next to the vCard one.

Comment: Is it enough to include thihs vCard information as QR code? - - If you include it, I think then it is not necessary to include QR code link to my ORCID.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: Enough for what purpose? For someone who doesn't use a QR code scanner, the information without the QR code will be "enough". In any case, the vCard and the ORCID ID serve two quite different purposes (although it may even be possible to integrate the ORCID ID as a custom field in the vCard).

Comment: What do you think have the QR-code on the frontside of the card? I already show my phone QR-code many times nowadays, instead giving my business card, because it is so much easier for the receiver too. You can integrate some piece of your business logo/art/... etc with the QR code.